# Login into Facebook with PHP script, but let me logged in the browser after the end of this script

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, curl, twitter

Please, I am solving this problem.. I need to login into Facebook or Twitter or any other website from my PHP script running on my server. I am normaly doing that with CURL, saving cookies to some predefined file.
But now I need something new.. I need to stay logged in with my browser, even when the script ends the login process.
Is that something simple, I can't see.. or am I going into complicated territory?
Something tells me, I would need to use javascript to set all cookies and sending the login data form?

If anyone has done loging into Facebook or Twitter with javascript, can you share some tips or the complete script with me, please?

Thanks for any tips and explaining me the overall logic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you use this for? Sounds like suspiciously spammish behaviour to me...?

Comment: I took this job at getafreelancer, I thought they need curl automatic login at first. Now, I can't complete the project, I really haven't found the way. Spammish? I don't know what exactly they need it for. But I can imagine many non-spaming reasons. For spamming, it would be in curl. But I was developing lot of spams too and in the end.. I don't care. It's classical blackhat versus whitehat dilema. In the end, the WH techniques are pretty BH and people do care about money only. I am not saying it's right.. it just is like this.

Comment: It's all relative for me.. for example you may be employed by big financial institution, programming their Financial software and thinking how perfect job you have. People think about financial, it's very high rated, reputable territory. Heh.. for me, they are all stealers.. when you understand the logic of money and banks. But I made it as an example only. All is pretty relative for me. Sometimes I want to spam facebook instead of making perfect bank tool for robbing clients :)

Answer (score 2):

I would look into [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php), More info [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Trying_Out_Facebook_Connect) and [here](http://onlinewebapplication.com/2011/08/login-facebook-twitter-php.html).

Comment: Thank you all very much for your answers.. but I need in general this functionality not only for Facebook, but also for Twitter and many other login forms in general. I would need to fake real browser login with my PHP or javascript script and let the user logged in after the script finishes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For your next job :) After a little surfing I found [a script](http://geekalicio.us/2009/04/24/logging-into-facebook-with-php-and-curl/) you (and sometimes me) needed.

```
/*
* Login to facebook
* $login_email : Account to login with
* $login_pass : Account password
*
* Returns true if logged in successfully, false otherwise
* Echoes any login error code
*
* Matt Smith - geekalicio.us
* Apr 23, 2009
*/
function fb_login($login_email, $login_pass){

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'charset_test=%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84&locale=en_US&email='.urlencode($login_email).'&pass='.urlencode($login_pass).'&pass_placeholder=&charset_test=%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__)).'/fb_cookies.txt');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__)).'/fb_cookies.txt');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3 GTB5");
 curl_exec($ch);

 $err = 0;
 $err = curl_errno($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 if ($err != 0){
 echo 'error='.$err."\n";
 return(false);
 } else {
 return(true);
 }

}
```

and then you can load home page with

```
if (fb_login($login_email,$login_pass)){
$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'charset_test=%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84&locale=en_US&email='.urlencode($login_email).'&pass='.urlencode($login_pass).'&pass_placeholder=&charset_test=%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__)).'/fb_cookies.txt');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__)).'/fb_cookies.txt');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3 GTB5");
$html = curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);

  echo $html;
}
```

Whole script I'm using located at http://pastie.org/619912 .
And yes, use it for good, not for evil :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supposed to be possible.  When your PHP script logs in, it gets an authentication token/cookie for Facebook.  That cookie is private and not supposed to be used on any other machine.  There are hackish ways to do it, but none I can recommend.